# Ruby: Getting undefined method errors NoMethodError

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby. One of my exercise to remove Arrowhead programming and raise an exception. I keep getting `undefined method for validate_region_and_shape`.

```
def self.classify(region, shape)
    # Alternative for raising exception within classify method
    #raise Error_Message unless CLASSIFICATIONS.include? (region)
    #raise Error_Message unless CLASSIFICATIONS[region].include? (shape)
    if validate_region_and_shape(region, shape)
    places = CLASSIFICATIONS[region][shape]
    "You have a(n) '#{places}'"
    end
  end

  def validate_region_and_shape(region, shape)
      raise Error_Message if valid_region?
      raise Error_Message if valid_shape?
  end

  def valid_region?
    CLASSIFICATIONS.include?(region)
  end

  def valid_shape?
    CLASSIFICATIONS[region].include?(shape)
  end

  end
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not compile, you have one too many `end`. The indentation makes it look like the `def`s are inside `def self.classify`. You've also substantially changed the code, the new code does not have your original problem. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Also, should `valid_region?` method be taking `region` as an arg and similarly `valid_shape` be taking `shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just have a typo when defining `validate_region_and_shape?`

Edit:

If you need to get rid of exceptions, then you could try something like

```
def validate_region_and_shape(region, shape)
  CLASSIFICATIONS.include?(region) && CLASSIFICATIONS[region].include?(shape)
end

def classify(region, shape)
  # Alternative for raising exception within classify method
  #raise Error_Message unless CLASSIFICATIONS.include? (region)
  #raise Error_Message unless CLASSIFICATIONS[region].include? (shape)
  if validate_region_and_shape?(region, shape)
    arrowhead = CLASSIFICATIONS[region][shape]
    "You have a(n) '#{arrowhead}' arrowhead. Probably priceless."
  else
   raise Error_Message
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried. They suggested when a method called ? should do nothing other than return a true or false. It should not raise exceptions. I'm trying to put validation in separate method.

Comment: @YoussefKaib It's not very clear what you are asking, can you elaborate further on your what you are trying to do? I have edited my answer, is that the kind of thing you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things going on here. For one, you're using two different names for your `validate_region_and_shape` method. You're calling it with a question mark, but it's defined without one. So, either change this:

```
if validate_region_and_shape?(r...
```

to:

```
if validate_region_and_shape(r...
```

Or change:

```
def validate_region_and_shape(r...
```

to:

```
def validate_region_and_shape?(r...
```

You're also defining it as an instance method (no `self`), but calling it from the class method. Since there is no instance, there is no instance method with that name. So, you'll need to make it a class method like the first one...

```
def self.validate_region_and_shape(region, shape)
  raise ...
```